# android facebook permissions issue

Tags: android, facebook

My Exception is as follows

```
com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException:
ApiException:The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time.
```

but I have given

```
private final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
loginButton.setPublishPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Such issues arise due to continuous install and uninstall during debugging, Please try to uninstall both your app and Facebook app from device and re install, try to remove your app from Facebook permission as well.